# Path RenderTransform not equal to Border around it with RenderTransform?

Tags: wpf, xaml, rendertransform

I had expected the following two pieces of XAML to produce the same output. However, the RenderTransform on the Path uses some funky rotation point that I don't understand. Can someone explain to me why these two pieces of XAML are not equivalent?

```
<Window x:Class="CenterPathTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="50"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Border Width="100" Height="200">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="70" Y="-100"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Path Width="100" Height="200" Stretch="Uniform"
                Data="M 0,20M 20,0M 6.04,4.51 C6.04,4.51 7.54,3 7.54,3 7.54,3 14.5,10 14.5,10 14.5,10 7.54,17 7.54,17 7.54,17 6.04,15.48 6.04,15.48 6.04,15.48 11.5,10 11.5,10 11.5,10 6.04,4.51 6.04,4.51 z" />
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I consider the behavior on this one following to be incorrect:

```
<Window x:Class="CenterPathTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="50"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Path Width="100" Height="200" Stretch="Uniform"
            Data="M 0,20M 20,0M 6.04,4.51 C6.04,4.51 7.54,3 7.54,3 7.54,3 14.5,10 14.5,10 14.5,10 7.54,17 7.54,17 7.54,17 6.04,15.48 6.04,15.48 6.04,15.48 11.5,10 11.5,10 11.5,10 6.04,4.51 6.04,4.51 z">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="70" Y="-100"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: You're missing your [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) (aka, your "funky rotation point") so the object doesn't know how it started so it knows how to end up after you've applied your other transforms.

Comment: `RenderTransformOrigin` defaults to 0,0. That's what I want. I cannot use `RenderTransformOrigin` to set the origin for the transform on the path because I don't know what the ratio to the rotation point is. It seems related to the `Stretch` on the path.

Comment: Nah it should be going from the parent thats setting its relative bounds, and actually you usually want .5,.5 since it's dead center, otherwise you're coming out of a corner literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the rotation point being related to the `Stretch` property on your second example.
To test this, you can change your XAML so that both examples have `Stretch="None"`, and you can see that they perfectly overlap.

Your second example is a good example on how not to do it. :)  When you have a path object and are stretching it by some unknown amount, your default `RenderTransformOrigin` is also stretched/moved.

The first example works as expected, because you are doing the `TranslateTransform` and the `RotateTransform` on the `Border` object which hasn't been stretched or scaled.  The `Path` object inside the border is then free to scale up to the needed dimensions without being adversely affected by the transforms that are occurring on the parent object (the `Border`).

In order to get your second example to behave identically to the first, you need to figure out the exact scale factor that occurs when the `Path` is stretched to fit your 100x200 size bounds.  Then you would have to use that number to either calculate a new `RenderTransformOrigin` or to calculate new X and Y values for the `TranslateTransform`.

..or..

Change the `Data` in the second `Path` object to draw the chevron at the full 'stretched' size initially.

Given the complexity of either of those solutions, leaving the `Path` inside the `Border` object is by far the easiest route.